# query_post / same posts on page 2 -3

Tags: wordpress, pagination, blogs

I have a custom theme and I've asked the theme's creator for help but while waiting for an answer(they take forever) I thought I'd post here as well

My blog is showing the same posts on page 2 and 3 as it does on page 1.

I found this code on my page-blog.php template

```
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) {
   the_post();
```

and lower down on the page:

```
<ul class="pagination">

<?php
if ($paginar == '1') {
   gym_pagination();
}
else
{
   next_posts_link('&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' );
   previous_posts_link('Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' );
}
?>

</ul>
```

The blog address is: http://absolutept.com/blog/

Does anyone have suggestions on whether the way this is written is the problem and if so, how should it read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That theme creator should know better that using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Straight from the codex

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

The correct way of doing this is using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Your query should look something like this

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
     <--rest of your arguments-->
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

         <-----Your Loop---->

}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

For pagination to work properly, you need to modify the `next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages );` link by adding the `$max_pages` parameter. So your `next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages );` should look like this

```
next_posts_link('&larr; '.'Older posts', $the_query->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: Thank you for the code // this should solve our problem

Comment: Good luck. Just remember to accept my answer if this solves your problem :)